# How to enable Unicode in Excel 2016 VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, excel-2016, vbe

I have a worksheet with Hebrew word "שלום" in cell A1.

I am trying to run this VBA code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim str As String
    str = Range("A1")
    MsgBox str
End Sub
```

The message box displays:

> ????

Also, when I try to write Hebrew characters in VBA code:

```
if range("A1") = "שלום" then 'do something...'
```

instead of Hebrew letters I see gibberish.

I use Excel 2016 on Windows 10. Hebrew language pack is installed.

I did not face this problem in Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

Anyone with an idea for enabling Hebrew (or Unicode in general) in VBA code?

Comment: There better alternatives to **MsgBox**  See:  http://blog.nkadesign.com/2013/vba-unicode-strings-and-the-windows-api/

Comment: Thanks, but my main goal is to be able to use hebrew characters inside the code...

Comment: Then use ***ChrW()*** with a suitable font.

Comment: Have you tried VB Editor --> Tools --> Options --> Editor Format --> Font?

Comment: It is always amazing how american programs are baffled by the fact that other alphabets exist... Éáöüóúőí. Ű.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set system locale to Hebrew.

Different version of Windows has a slightly different way of doing it. Search the net for how to do it on your version of Windows. Basically, it is in Control Panel/Language & Region. If you are using Windows 10, it is under Settings/Time & Language/Region/Additional Date, Time, & Regional Setting (on the upper right hand corner of the window)/Region (change date, time, or number formats)/Administrative.