# How to display Japanese characters in VBA editor?

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, vbe

I can't set Sheet.Name property in Japanese. Event file name also displays in maybe Chinese? All display well in Excel.

How can I set up the VBA editor to work with Japanese?

I changed region to Japanese.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745025/how-to-enable-unicode-in-excel-2016-vba-editor

Comment: @stifin, none of that is working. I think Editor itself not recognition Japanese string

Comment: you mean if you set your entire system to Japanese, it doesn't work? I would expect that that _should_ work, otherwise it implies that Japanese people can't use VBA without using English Windows

Comment: yeah, don't know where it was going wrong. Window display, Administration, Region, time all I changed to 日本.

Comment: followed by restart -- as I think Windows won't switch code pages without the restart

Comment: I was restarted. VBA menu display Japanese but other places in VBA editor was not.

Comment: it's been a long time since I worked with dbcs, but I remember that there were places where you still would see "???". However, if you displayed wide characters in a font that supports those characters, they could still display in the UI... but this is just my memory going back over 10 years ago

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Generally, share _text_ rather than _picture of text_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got to the right point.

this post is in Japanese but by picture so not hard to see that in Admitration we must **uncheck** [Header: World Wide language support ... use Unicode UTF-8]

maybe as @stifin mentioned, it is about wide character.
[Answer](https://qiita.com/callmekohei/items/334b7ac93dfe2791e927)